# Basic DataTable Ajax Configuration Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to use DataTables with php and mysql. I have an ajax call that is pulling in data as such:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "ptid":"blah",
        "last_name":"blah",
        "first_name":"blah",
        "priv_application":"E",
        "priv_document":"E",
        "priv_note":"E",
    }
]
```

I'm configuring DataTables with the following:

```
$('#listing').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "select": true,
    ajax: {
            url: '{{ url("administration/admindata") }}',
            dataSrc: ''
     },
     columns: [
        { title: "ID" },
        { title: "PtID" },
        { title: "Last Name" },
        { title: "First Name" },
        { title: "Application" },
        { title: "Documents" },
        { title: "Notes" }
    ]
});
```

And the HTML for the table is as follows:

```
<table id="listing" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

However, it doesn't want to load the data even though this configuration is exactly like the first example given here:
https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

I'm getting the following error:
DataTables warning: table id=listing - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a non-standard-ASCII quotation mark before your `id`, it also lacks the colon.

Comment: Sorry, that was user error in entering the info for the question. Should be: "id":"3",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using array of objects as your data source, you need to specify data source for each column using [`columns.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option.

```
$('#listing').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "select": true,
    "ajax": {
       "url": '{{ url("administration/admindata") }}',
       "dataSrc": ''
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "id", title: "ID" },
        { data: "ptid", title: "PtID" },
        { data: "last_name", title: "Last Name" },
        { data: "first_name", title: "First Name" },
        { data: "priv_application", title: "Application" },
        { data: "priv_adocument", title: "Documents" },
        { data: "priv_note", title: "Notes" }
   ]
});
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly it, was missing the data source. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
ajax": {
     type': 'POST',
     'url': "<?=action('TestController@postTestfunction')?>"
},
```

try to use the ajax call without blade template code.
and make sure your route is written something like this.

```
Route::controller('test', 'TestController');
```

Also try with change your controller function name "admindata" to "postAdmindata"

Let me know still if you get stuck anywhere.